# Trying to replicate this title page: page grid and image

Tags: titles, layout

I am trying to achieve the following result:

1. Get a grid over the title page
2. Have a figure that looks like a stock price process

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

[image: GOAL]

Comment: For the layout, you should take alook at the `titling` mackage, which  has some tools to custimise `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tikz` version of the mountain range:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{vua}{RGB}{106,153,218}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,remember picture,overlay,scale=4.1,yshift=-1.7cm,xshift=-1.7cm]
\shadedraw[vua,top color=vua!30!white, bottom color=white,ultra thick]  (0.4235,7.2111) -- (0.4817,7.2296) -- (0.5329,7.2404) -- (0.5531,7.1788) -- (0.5959,7.1293) -- (0.6374,7.1233) -- (0.6555,7.1050) -- (0.6952,7.1397) -- (0.7293,7.1693) -- (0.7459,7.0832) -- (0.7954,7.0434) -- (0.8272,7.1134) -- (0.8642,7.1423) -- (0.9119,7.2006) -- (0.9764,7.1723) -- (0.9984,7.1256) -- (1.0216,7.1517) -- (1.0439,7.1797) -- (1.0912,7.1256) -- (1.1394,7.0867) -- (1.2079,7.0282) -- (1.2411,6.9956) -- (1.2826,6.9526) -- (1.3213,6.9121) -- (1.3700,6.9439) -- (1.4111,6.9602) -- (1.4498,6.7843) -- (1.4737,6.7972) -- (1.4882,6.8109) -- (1.5118,6.7241) -- (1.5474,6.6155) -- (1.5861,6.5290) -- (1.6488,6.4263) -- (1.6735,6.4628) -- (1.7218,6.5092) -- (1.7587,6.5116) -- (1.7768,6.4481) -- (1.8204,6.3702) -- (1.8582,6.3455) -- (1.9301,6.3196) -- (1.9637,6.2909) -- (2.0110,6.1985) -- (2.0849,6.0881) -- (2.1081,6.0465) -- (2.1249,6.0683) -- (2.1405,6.0900) -- (2.1643,6.0092) -- (2.2058,5.9980) -- (2.2462,6.0963) -- (2.2776,6.0122) -- (2.2969,5.9441) -- (2.3590,6.0104) -- (2.3963,6.0443) -- (2.4195,6.0483) -- (2.4771,6.3049) -- (2.5167,6.4263) -- (2.6031,6.4744) -- (2.6262,6.5306) -- (2.6448,6.5757) -- (2.6638,6.5399) -- (2.6949,6.4636) -- (2.7642,6.2239) -- (2.8125,6.1192) -- (2.8482,6.0591) -- (2.8912,6.0216) -- (2.9065,6.0402) -- (2.9313,5.9722) -- (2.9859,5.8908) -- (3.0013,5.9079) -- (3.0841,5.9219) -- (3.1528,5.7742) -- (3.1860,5.6956) -- (3.2203,5.6106) -- (3.2778,5.6701) -- (3.2911,5.6696) -- (3.3108,5.5924) -- (3.3267,5.5248) -- (3.3718,5.5913) -- (3.4261,5.6778) -- (3.4580,5.6168) -- (3.4969,5.5489) -- (3.5292,5.5009) -- (3.5421,5.4505) -- (3.5751,5.4092) -- (3.6164,5.4295) -- (3.6316,5.4530) -- (3.6515,5.3443) -- (3.6685,5.2281) -- (3.6975,5.2587) -- (3.7162,5.3024) -- (3.7330,5.2910) -- (3.7838,5.2619) -- (3.8352,5.3058) -- (3.9191,5.2277) -- (3.9397,5.1066) -- (3.9584,5.1212) -- (3.9795,5.1332) -- (3.9934,5.0876) -- (4.0281,4.9995) -- (4.0684,4.8470) -- (4.0871,4.7342) -- (4.1169,4.7508) -- (4.1329,4.7790) -- (4.1718,4.7173) -- (4.2116,4.6517) -- (4.2330,4.7404) -- (4.2530,4.8354) -- (4.2703,4.8276) -- (4.3042,4.8354) -- (4.3264,4.8524) -- (4.3602,4.6968) -- (4.3789,4.7038) -- (4.3977,4.7140) -- (4.4165,4.6833) -- (4.4527,4.6510) -- (4.5342,4.5085) -- (4.6302,4.2735) -- (4.6911,4.3614) -- (4.7087,4.4070) -- (4.7279,4.3524) -- (4.7632,4.2626) -- (4.7990,4.1987) -- (4.8353,4.1614) -- (4.8759,4.1041) -- (4.9534,4.0030) -- (4.9897,3.9676) -- (5.0243,3.9258) -- (5.0762,3.9839) -- (5.1137,4.0976) -- (5.1605,4.3093) -- (5.1891,4.5210) -- (5.2722,4.9245) -- (5.3006,5.0129) -- (5.3382,5.0565) -- (5.3738,5.0281) -- (5.3944,5.0378) -- (5.4314,4.9877) -- (5.4670,4.9343) -- (5.5165,4.9530) -- (5.5366,5.0470) -- (5.5579,5.1297) -- (5.5756,5.1219) -- (5.5905,5.1168) -- (5.6119,5.2214) -- (5.6501,5.3429) -- (5.6966,5.4970) -- (5.7298,5.5267) -- (current page.south east) -- (current page.south west) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is coming close! Is there a way to somehow hide all the code that is necessary, because the code looks huge in the file. Furthermore, is adjusting the positioning possible?

Comment: The position adjustment is resolved. But the code is still taking a huge amount of space

Comment: @Sean Well, your stock price curve contains a lot of data, if you want it shorter, you could approximate it with a rectangle :)

Comment: ahh, never mind then, because the result looks stunning! Last question, any idea how I can create a grid over the page? Thanks for answering on the Christmas eve ;-)

Comment: @Sean Are you sure the grid is a good idea? To me it looks like someone forgot to switch off the debugging lines for the layout before producing the final version.

Comment: Actually, I agree, this looks very nice.

Comment: @Sean One small warning: make sure that your printing method of choice supports boarderless printing -- otherwise this design might look odd if it is surounded by an empty boarder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87467/discussion-between-sean-and-samcarter).

Comment: @Sean: You can put all the code in a second file, say `titlepage.tex` and then simply `\input{titlepage}` in your main document.

Answer (score 6):

Very similar to @samcarter's nice answer and also a grid. (I am not very enthusiastic about punching in texts from a screen shot, so I let it be, but it will be straightforward to add the nodes or to use whatever template you have for that.) A local coordinate system a la [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799) is installed.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % probably not necessary when using a template with titlepage
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[dotted] let \p1=($(current page.north east)-(current page.south west)$),
\n1={(\x1+2pt)/7},\n2={(\y1+2pt)/8}
in \pgfextra{\xdef\myw{\x1}}
foreach \X in {1,...,6}
{([xshift=-1pt+\X*\n1,yshift=-1pt]current page.south west) --
([xshift=-1pt+\X*\n1,yshift=1pt]current page.north west)}
foreach \X in {1,...,7}
{([xshift=-1pt,yshift=-1pt+\X*\n2]current page.south west) --
([xshift=1pt,yshift=-1pt+\X*\n2]current page.south east)};
\draw[blue,shift={(current page.south west)},top color=blue!30,bottom color=white] 
  plot[variable=\x,domain=0:\myw,samples=61,smooth] 
({\x*1pt},{0.7*\x*1pt+(2*\myw/(\myw+\x))*sin((\x*1pt/\myw)*630)*60pt-
pow(\x/\myw,4)*140pt+20pt*rand}) % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28463/121799
 -- ++(2mm,0) --
([xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]current page.south east)
-- ([xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm]current page.south west);
\begin{scope}[x={($(current page.south east)-(current page.south west)$)},
y={($(current page.north west)-(current page.south west)$)},
shift={(current page.south west)}] % inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799
\draw  (0.2,0.8) -- (0.8,0.8)  (0.2,0.6) -- (0.8,0.6);
\fill[white] (0.25,0.62) rectangle (0.75,0.78);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to have the figure look a little more like the stock price process as in the example?

Comment: nice answer! Are these the honey liquor stock prices?

Comment: @samcarter No, obviously these are the "Blauberge", see [here](https://www.hoehenrausch.de/huetten/blaubergalm/). ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oh, I got confused because no marmots were visible -- but of course they are all hibernating at the moment.

Comment: @samcarter Some time ago, a relative of mine (called "Mausi" by humans) lived on Blaubergalm. Unfortunately she got killed by a cow. AFAIK she didn't hibernate much during winter.

Comment: @marmot What an unfortunate destiny! Maybe hibernating would have been safer.

Comment: I think that happened during summer, cows are usually in the valley during winter. (Ironically, the lady who is or at least used to be on the hut is Dutch and produces Gouda cheese on the hut. Maybe this inspired the OP's choice for the cover, and all the stock market blabla is just made up? ;-)

Comment: Hahah, I am Dutch tho. But it's a cover for a financial report, so has nothing to do with mountains!

Comment: @Sean You should switch your field, I'd say. ;-)

Comment: @marmot haha, I prefer not, 6 years of study in the books already :-O

Comment: @Sean Amsterdam seems also not the best place to study mountains :)